# How should I add a host name to /etc/hosts?

Tags: networking, hostname

There are several answers on how to change hostname of Ubuntu, and all of them propose to do "the same changes" to `/etc/hosts`. "The same" stands for "the same as in `/etc/hostanme`". But unfotunately, these files have completely different formats, and they can't be changed in "same" manner.

So, the question is: what to write in `hosts` to have hostname `myname`?

Currently my `hosts` contains:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

and some IPv6 stuff which I don't understand.

So, should I replace `localhost` with `myname`, really?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, really. The `/etc/hosts` file is just a map that links IPs to hostnames. If you want to be able to do things like `ssh myname` and have that run `ssh localhost`, you need to add a line that identifies localhost (127.0.0.1) as `myname`:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 myname
```

You could just replace `localhost` with `myname`, but then things like `ssh localhost` would fail and `localhost` is pretty standard. So just add another line as shown above.

Comment: Use just one line: '127.0.0.1 localhost myname`

Comment: I wouldn't use it in one line. Usually I use `127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost` and `127.0.0.1 myserver.mydomain myserver` to keep things a bit more structured

Comment: The wording is a bit fuzzy on if having two different lines for the same IP is valid but I would believe it isn't _"...one line per IP address"_ [hosts(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/hosts.5.html)