# Missing /etc/hosts file – How can I create a new hosts file?

Tags: command-line, filesystem, hosts

I have googled and searched Ask Ubuntu on this, but got no relevant answers.
I have no `hosts` file in `/etc`, I cannot find a `hosts` file in search, I am talking about the system hosts file not `lampp/etc`. I mention that because there is no hosts file there either - maybe that is a clue.

I want to know how to create a `hosts` file in Ubuntu or obtain a sample file I could copy and paste or I am happy to use the terminal if someone can help with best way to create the file and edit it.

I am not even sure what extension it should have - basically I just want the default `hosts` file that I understand Ubuntu should come with in my `/etc` folder.

Comment: The default contents are created by the `netbase` package. See `/var/lib/dpkg/info/netbase.postinst`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lines in the `/etc/hosts` file have the following format:

```
<IP> <HOSTNAME>.<DOMAIN> <ALIAS>
```

You can create and/or edit the file with your preferred editor:

```bsh
sudo nano /etc/hosts     # with nano in a terminal
gksudo gedit /etc/hosts  # with gedit
kdesudo kate /etc/hosts  # with kate
```

Here are some useful lines for the file – lines beginning with `#` are comments and get ignored, empty lines are allowed:

```bsh
# The following line is desirable for IPv4 capable hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1             localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1         ip6-allnodes
ff02::2         ip6-allrouters
```

You can read more about the format and get examples on the manpage ([How can I get help on terminal commands?](https://askubuntu.com/q/991946/507051)):

```bsh
man hosts
```

There's also a [Howto on ubuntuforums.org](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=3407).

Further reading:

- [What is the use of /etc/hosts?](https://askubuntu.com/q/183176/507051)
- [What are the default settings for 'etc/hosts' and 'etc/hostname'?](https://askubuntu.com/q/880270/507051)
- [How should I add a host name to /etc/hosts?](https://askubuntu.com/q/940629/507051)